# Pandas: How to summarize data, groupby, unique

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the dataframe I'm using:

```
company | pc-serial | software
--------+-----------+--------------------
A       | 1         | Word
A       | 1         | Excel
A       | 2         | Word
A       | 3         | PowerPoint
B       | 4         | Word
B       | 4         | Excel
B       | 4         | Visio
B       | 5         | Word
B       | 5         | PowerPoint
```

I want to build a new dataframe that tells me the number of unique softwares each company has, the result should be something like:

```
company | unique_sw
--------+--------------
A       | 3
B       | 4
```

A has 3 (Word, Excel and PowerPoint), B has 4 (Word, Excel, PowerPoint and Visio)

I tried `df.groupby('company')['software'].count()` it gives me the count of all the software A has 4 and B has 5. If I change the `count()` for `unique()` it will give me the first occurence of "software".

So I got no idea on how to aggregate this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
df.groupby('company')['software'].nunique()
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
df.groupby('company').software.apply(lambda x : len(set(x))).to_frame('uniquecount')
Out[687]: 
         uniquecount
company             
A                  3
B                  4
```

Or you can fix your code by `drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop_duplicates(['company','software']).groupby('company').software.count()
Out[690]: 
company
A    3
B    4
Name: software, dtype: int64
```